# Getting Distinct or FirstOrDefault with Breeze Client-Side

Tags: breeze

A query already executed with breeze on the client side and I store the results locally. I was really hoping to either `.Distinct()` or `.FirstOrDefault()` on the client side so that I can execute locally instead of going back to the server.

I know that breeze has limited capabilities on the client side. I've looked through the samples and no luck there.
http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/query-examples

Can breeze do this? Is this something that they will be doing in the future?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to see your query to answer properly.

In almost all cases, **`take(1)` is equivalent to `firstOrDefault`** and works fine on both remote and local queries.

```
var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from('Persons')
      .where('FirstName', 'eq', 'Lizzy')
      .take(1); // will return one or null
```

If you want to find an entity by its key, looking first in the cache and then going remote if necessary, then you should consider the [`fetchEntityByKey` method](http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/EntityManager.html#method_fetchEntityByKey).

`Distinct` only makes sense for projection queries in which the objects returned (which are NOT entities, btw) have no id. Can't know if that is what you need until you show me your query.

With due respect, I feel that hunch_hunch's answer is a bit misleading. Please reconsider checking MY ANSWER as the best answer.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing yet built into breeze that will do this. I've run into the same thing, and had to call `.Distinct()` and `.FirstOrDefault()` on the server side. There is an [outstanding suggestion](https://breezejs.uservoice.com/forums/173093-1-breezejs-feature-suggestions/suggestions/4346532-support-for-distinct-query) from last year in the breeze forums (currently at #10 on the list by vote count) to add `.Distinct()`-like functionality.

Comment: I did not know they had a suggestions to improve breeze. Thanks! I hope they do implement it. For now I'm looking through already executed query stored into an array with a look up method to do '.FirstOrDefault()'. As for '.Distinct()', I have no choice but to load it to server side too.